# Посоветуйте книгу-учебник по Javascript

Tags: javascript

Несколько крайних лет разрабатываю на jQuery. Решил изучить нативный Javascript для движения в сторону разработки на React.

Гугл выдает множество "лучших" книг по моему запросу, но все перечитать не хватит времени. Обязательно нужно что-то свежее, после перехода на ES6.

Подскажите хорошую книгу, пожалуйста.

Comment: Мы вам сейчас точно так же "выдадим множество "лучших" книг по вашему запросу, но все перечитать не хватит времени."

Comment: @Kromster зато это будут ваши книги, с комментариями

Comment: Это, по сути, ничем не будет отличаться от книжного с рейтингами. Вот там лучше и искать ответ на ваш вопрос ) *пишу это исключительно из конструктивных соображений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"You dont know java script"** от автора Кейли Симпсон - вот вам серия потрясающих книг после прочтения которых станете гуру JS!
Ссылка на русифицированные книги: https://github.com/azat-io/you-dont-know-js-ru

Comment: Спасибо, серия действительно, по описанию, отличная. Жаль, бумажные русские варианты отсутствуют. Будем искать :)